# auto login for skydrive api php

Tags: onedrive

I want to make just offline authentication in SkyDrive api PHP,just want to provide client_id,client_secret_key and access or refresh token which may be preferable and than authenticate me on that basis.After successful offline login create one folder in SkyDrive (OneDrive) and upload files inside that created folder.

And how to refresh access token automatically without login.

Please help me out if anyone have idea regarding that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got it,

Please use the Following source it's work for me
https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive

Within that Below File is so useful
https://github.com/lovattj/php-skydrive/blob/master/src/functions.inc.php

i changed in curl function and it's work for me

For e.g

i replaced curl_get function by below and it work for me

```
protected function curl_get($uri, $json_decode_output="true", $expected_status_code="HTTP/1.1 200 OK") {                                    
                try{
                        $ch = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
                        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    // we want headers
                        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true); 
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                               
                        $result = curl_exec($ch);                                                                                               
                        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);                                                
                        curl_close($ch);
                }  catch (Exception $e){}
                if ($httpcode == "201" || $httpcode == "200") {
        return json_decode($result, true);
                } else {
                        return array('error' => 'HTTP status code not expected - got ', 'description' => $httpcode);
                }                  
                var_dump(json_decode($result));                                        
}
```